# Algorithm for sorted weight distribution

Tags: algorithm, sorting, distribution

I have a list of `N_w` weights `w_i`, where the different weights are not (necessarily) equal. This list needs to be uniformly distributed in `N_b` ordered bins, where `N_b` < `N_w`, while *preserving order*.

**Example**

A list of weights `(1,2,1,5,3)` could be distributed into `3` bins as `(1,2,1)`, `(5)`, `(3)`. While it is not uniform, this is the optimal distribution under the constraint of preserving order.

Are there any *practical* algorithms that solves this problem (other than brute forcing it) that I could have a look at?

**Update**
The number of weights `N_w` is of `O(1e6)`. The number if bins is of `O(1e5)`. I'm looking for an algorithm ideally of at worst `O(N log N)`.

Comment: Without the constraint of "preserving order" this is a strong NP-Hard problem known as the k-partition. I believe for this variation where order is maintained there is a polynomial, or at least pseudo polynomial solution. Also note, brute force in here is `O(N_w^N_b)`. What is the scale of your problem?

Comment: What does optimal mean, exactly?

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Optimal in a sense that the difference of the sum of the weights between the largest and smallest bin is minimized.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use a hill climbing algorithm? Given the sequence of numbers, you have several dividers placed that separate the numbers into bins. Each mutation you move one divider one position. I'm hoping this approach would have no local- but only global optima.

Here a sample of how it would evaluate on your example. I'm evaluating a state based on the difference between the smallest and the largest bin. The notation is as follows:
*state* => *stateScore*

1. 1,2,153 => 8
2. 1,21,53 => 7
3. 12,1,53 => 7
4. 12,15,3 => 3
5. 121,5,3 => 2

Step (3) isn't really a hill climbing step, but it does stay on the same 'height', so it might still be workable.

Comment: could you please elaborate a little in your answer? Like how to determine which divider to move, when to stop, etc.